# Angular app Deployment to Azure - Failed to Start npm

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, npm

I am attempting to deploy my Angular application to Azure. While I can successfully publish my application using Azure, I receive the following error message when accessing the published site:

```
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start 'npm'. To resolve this:.

    [1] Ensure that 'npm' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
    Current PATH enviroment variable is: D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs;D:\Windows\system32;D:\Windows;D:\Windows\System32\Wbem;D:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet;D:\Program Files\Git\cmd;D:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6;D:\Python27;
    Make sure the executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.
```

My current app's directory is already using node(npm) version 8.11.3, so I am unsure why my application can't seem to find it.

Can someone help to point me in the right direction to solve this? I am an Azure newbie.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

App Service doesn't run Node app by default. Make sure you have specified 'WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION' parameter in the Application Setting pointing to the right version of Node.js. Restart the app once done.

Comment: I set the node parameter to 8.11.3(current verison) in my application settings in Azure, and it doesn't seem to fix the issue, still seeing the above error message.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the In Process hosting model in your .csproj:

`<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>`

This can cause issues with Angular SPAs - as per this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4206#issuecomment-445612167).

There is a workaround to solve this:

> We've added a helper to set current directory to correct value in 2.2 (https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module/samples_snapshot/2.x/CurrentDirectoryHelpers.cs) just call `CurrentDirectoryHelpers.SetCurrentDirectory()` as the first line of your `Program.cs`. We are also going to start setting current directory to correct value by default in 3.0.